# 3D Density/Relative Frequency Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, rgl, wireframe

I've been tasked with studying the duration and delay of a doctor's appointment book.

My approach so far has been to plot and analyze density charts by duration and by deviation of the appointed time, **separately**.

| Appointment ID | Duration | Deviation | Online/In person | Type of Punctuality/Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 min | - 10 min (late) | Online | Patient is Late |
| 2 | 2 min | - 5 min | In person | Doctor is late |
| 3 | 10 min | +5 min (ahead of time) | In person | On time |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1487 | 15 min | 0.2 min | Online | On time |

Now, I just want to print 3D bivariate kernel density plot, in **my Markdown PDF OUTPUT**

I can do a 2D density plot.

```
ggplot(final, aes(x=duration, y=deviation)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position='none') +
  xlim(0, quantile(as.numeric(final$duracion), 1-0.1)) +
  ylim(quantile(as.numeric(final$atraso), 0.01), quantile(as.numeric(final$atraso), 1-0.01))
```

[image: 2d bivariate density plot]

However, I would like to *extend the plot along the z-axis*, in a manner similar to what the following link shows.

(https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Distribution-of-sequence-and-genotype-derived-allele-frequencies-r-067-in-the-SNP_fig1_5555304)

After using kde2d(), rgl() and plot_ly() allow me to do so, but I can't embed the plots in my PDF output. Not to mention that plot_ly messes with one of my axis. And worst of all, I lose my non-numerical variables, which allow me to split the data and do useful comparisons with `facet_grid()`, or `aes(x, y, colour = )`.

Is there any way I can plot the density of **each pair of durations and deviations**, in a 3d graph? I've een researching about wireframe() + outer(), but there does not seem to be any density function for outer()

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think you're asking too many questions here, without providing any data.  You might be more successful if you just pick one part of the question,and prepare a dataset (probably a fake one) suitable for that part of the question.  Do you know how to compute a 2D density function?  Do you know how to plot one?  Do you know how to use other data to add colors to a surface plot?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us enough data or code to work with, so I'll show you how to embed a 3D plot of an unrelated function in a pdf document using `rgl`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2023-02-16"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(rgl)
setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)
```


```{r}
f <- function(x, y) { 
  r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
  ifelse(r == 0, 10, 10 * sin(r)/r)
}
open3d()
plot3d(f, col = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red")), 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Sinc( r )", 
       xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10),
       aspect = c(1, 1, 0.5))
```
````

This produces output that looks like this:

[image]